# Is there a way to translate this p5.js sketch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, p5.js

I'm developing my portfolio website (www.beatricebazzan.com). It turns out to be really slow and I detected that it depends on the p5.js file. If I hide it, the website works perfectly on every device. I was so wandering if there is a way to translate this sketch into a simple js file, that maybe is less heavy.

This is my sketch:

```
var provaHover;
var mouseIsOvering = false;
let img;

var p2Hover;
var mouseIsOvering2 = false;
let img2;

var p3Hover;
var mouseIsOvering3 = false;
let img3;

var p4Hover;
var mouseIsOvering4 = false;
let img4;

var p5Hover;
var mouseIsOvering5 = false;
let img5;

var p6Hover;
var mouseIsOvering6 = false;
let img6;

var p7Hover;
var mouseIsOvering7 = false;
let img7;

var p8Hover;
var mouseIsOvering8 = false;
let img8;

var p9Hover;
var mouseIsOvering9 = false;
let img9;

var p10Hover;
var mouseIsOvering10 = false;
let img10;

var p11Hover;
var mouseIsOvering11 = false;
let img11;

var p12Hover;
var mouseIsOvering12 = false;
let img12;

var p13Hover;
var mouseIsOvering13 = false;
let img13;

function preload() {}

function setup() {
  // let canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  let canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, 1600);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  // img = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/NiZiYUz.gif");
  img = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/portfolio/master/assets/intro/spleen-intro.gif");
  provaHover = select("#p01")

  img2 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/thelostgallery-intro.jpg");
  p2Hover = select("#p02")

  img3 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/physicalinternet-intro.jpg");
  p3Hover = select("#p03")

  img4 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/placemaking-intro.jpg");
  p4Hover = select("#p04")

  img5 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/portfolio/master/assets/intro/setjettersunited-intro.jpg");
  p5Hover = select("#p05")

  // img6 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/contratempo-intro.gif");
  img6 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/portfolio/master/assets/intro/contratempo-intro.png");
  p6Hover = select("#p06")

  img7 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/outforia_intro.gif");
  p7Hover = select("#p07")

  // img8 = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/uv8wnM7.gif");
  img8 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/portfolio/master/assets/images/fuso-tv.gif");
  p8Hover = select("#p08")

  img9 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/ihavegotnothingtowear-intro.png");
  p9Hover = select("#p09")

  img10 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/atavola-intro.jpg");
  p10Hover = select("#p10")

  img11 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/lineunit-intro.jpg");
  p11Hover = select("#p11")

  img12 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/thekingof-intro.gif");
  p12Hover = select("#p12")

  img13 = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BazziBeatrice/Portfolio/master/assets/intro/video-macchie-intro.gif");
  p13Hover = select("#p13")

}

function draw() {

  if (mouseIsOvering == true) {mostraImmagine();} else if (mouseIsOvering2 == true) {mostraImmagine2();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering3 == true) {mostraImmagine3();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering4 == true) {mostraImmagine4();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering5 == true) {mostraImmagine5();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering6 == true) {mostraImmagine6();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering7 == true) {mostraImmagine7();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering8 == true) {mostraImmagine8();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering9 == true) {mostraImmagine9();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering10 == true) {mostraImmagine10();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering11 == true) {mostraImmagine11();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering12 == true) {mostraImmagine12();
  } else if (mouseIsOvering13 == true) {mostraImmagine13();
  } else {clear();}
  // console.log(mouseIsOvering);
}

function mouseStatus(status) {mouseIsOvering = status;}
function mouseStatus2(status) {mouseIsOvering2 = status;}
function mouseStatus3(status) {mouseIsOvering3 = status;}
function mouseStatus4(status) {mouseIsOvering4 = status;}
function mouseStatus5(status) {mouseIsOvering5 = status;}
function mouseStatus6(status) {mouseIsOvering6 = status;}
function mouseStatus7(status) {mouseIsOvering7 = status;}
function mouseStatus8(status) {mouseIsOvering8 = status;}
function mouseStatus9(status) {mouseIsOvering9 = status;}
function mouseStatus10(status) {mouseIsOvering10 = status;}
function mouseStatus11(status) {mouseIsOvering11 = status;}
function mouseStatus12(status) {mouseIsOvering12 = status;}
function mouseStatus13(status) {mouseIsOvering13 = status;}

function mostraImmagine() {
  image(img, mouseX, mouseY + 20, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine2() {
  image(img2, mouseX, mouseY + 40, (img.width / 6), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine3() {
  image(img3, mouseX, mouseY + 40, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 7))}
function mostraImmagine4() {
  image(img4, mouseX, mouseY + 50, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 5))}
function mostraImmagine5() {
  image(img5, mouseX, mouseY - 30, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 6))}
function mostraImmagine6() {
  image(img6, mouseX, mouseY -40, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 5))}
function mostraImmagine7() {
  image(img7, mouseX, mouseY -100, (img.width / 6), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine8() {
  image(img8, mouseX, mouseY + 20, (img.width / 4.5), (img.height / 5))}
function mostraImmagine9() {
  image(img9, mouseX, mouseY - 20, (img.width / 3), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine10() {
  image(img10, mouseX, mouseY + 20, (img.width / 6), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine11() {
  image(img11, mouseX, mouseY - 60, (img.width / 5), (img.height / 4))}
function mostraImmagine12() {
  image(img12, mouseX, mouseY - 80, (img.width / 4), (img.height / 4.5))}
function mostraImmagine13() {
  image(img13, mouseX, mouseY - 140, (img.width / 5.5), (img.height / 4))}
```

and this is a part of the index where I link it:

```
                    <div id="p01" onmouseover="mouseStatus(true);" onmouseout="mouseStatus(false);">
                        <h1 id="main-subtitle" class="text-hover margin-index-top">
                            <a href="pages/spleen.html" id="project01" class="text-hover shadow-phone pointer">1. SPLEEN / editorial design</a>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
```

thank you a lot.

Comment: My first tip would be to not try an convert it line by line, and step back, look at teh problem, and then solve it in normal js. The only other thing I would say is make an array of images, that code is really hard to read.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with plain js, but I was having trouble in having the effect of the picture following the mouse and also recording the route of the picture (as you can see in https://beatricebazzan.com when you hover a title. If you have some kind of suggestions for that I would be grateful! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

So, as been pointed out, the code is a bit hard to read. Using some **For-loops** and loading your images in arrays would help, as well as to draw images to the screen.

Beyond this, you're using a number of animated gifs, and these can be quite large and take a while to load. I'm not sure I understand:

> If I hide it, the website works perfectly on every device.

Are you saying if you don't run your p5.js sketch the website runs normally? I don't know if I understand how that's possibly as your setup() is loading in lots of image files.

Recommendations are to: clean up your code and reduce your file sizes.

p5.js itself is not that large, so the resources to load that shouldn't be contributing too much to lag.